# unable to resove termios in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

I'm currently working on PyDev project on Eclipse where I need to use the termios module available on Python. However my PyDev Eclipse environment fails to recognise it and gives a "Unable to Resolve:termios" error. However I'm able to resolve the same from my command line Python console where 'import termios' does not report any error. Is there any configuration that needs to be done on Eclipse to enable it resolve termios and other posix specific APIs. My Python version information is as below
 TIA!

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Check your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable as seen by Eclipse.

Comment: @cdarke yes it worked! thanks for the tip... I had to add the path for `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload` which contains the termios.so , additionally I also added the termios keyword under "Forced Builtins" tab

Comment: Can I suggest that you create an answer for your own question?  That might help others in the future.

Comment: @cdarke Done! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the solution**
Right click on your python project on Eclipse and click on "Properties" and follow the steps below:

1. Click on `Configure an Interpreter not listed`
   [image: Click on Configure an Interpreter not listed]
2. Click on `New Folder` under the Libraries tab and select the folder
   containing termios shared object, in my case it was located in
   `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload`
   [image: PYTHONPATH]
3. Add `termios` to the list of `Forced Builtins` tab by clicking on
   `New`
   [image: ForcedBuiltins]

Hope this helps, cheers!